# Accesibilidad Web

Tags: bug, colas-de-revisión, modo-oscuro

### Problemas de Accesibilidad Web

Me he encontrado con una situación en el modo oscuro de **Stack Overflow**. Se trata de un problema serio de contraste de acuerdo a la siguiente vista previa:

[image: Problema de contraste]

Es demasiado costoso distinguir el texto del fondo, por lo que se dificulta seriamente la revisión de ediciones sugeridas de otros usuarios, tal y como se puede observar en la siguiente tabla comparativa:

| Código fuente del autor | Cambio propuesto por otro usuario |
| --- | --- |
| [image] | [image] |

Se puede observar en la tabla anterior la dificultad que puede provocar la revisión de las ediciones sugeridas debido a problemas de contraste.

### Propuesta

Una propuesta de cambio sería:

- Eliminar la línea que atraviesa el código (`text-decoration: line-through;`).
- Aumentar la intensidad del rojo y establecer una opacidad adecuada (podría ser 20% de opacidad) para que se pueda visualizar mejor.

Es decir, tal como se ilustraría en la siguiente imagen:

[image: vista-previa-propuesta]

Esto ayudaría a visualizar mejor el código fuente del autor con el propuesto por otro usuario. El objetivo es verificar si hubo simplemente formateo de código o cambios en él con relativa facilidad.

Por lo que nuestra regla CSS podría quedar así:

```css
span.diff-delete {
  color: var(--red-700);
  background-color: rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.2);
}
```

Si se considera la propuesta anterior podríamos tener algo parecido a la siguiente tabla comparativa:

| Código fuente del autor | Cambio propuesto por otro usuario |
| --- | --- |
| [image] | [image] |

Allí, se puede notar que se hace más fácil comparar código.

Pueden visitar [este enlace](https://es.stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/258383) para que puedan observar el ejemplo mencionado en esta publicación en el modo oscuro.

Comment: GEnial!!! pero esta clase de propuestas debe ir en https://meta.stackexchange.com ya que es un cambio que impacta a toda la red!!! :)

Comment: Por supuesto.. avisa.. fijate que no la hayan publicado antes.. y la vamos corrigiendo entre todos...

Comment: Estoy revisando en **Stack Exchange** si existe o no un planteamiento similar. Apenas, publique avisaré por acá.

Comment: Listo, ya la publiqué bajo el título [**Code marked as deleted does not look good**](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/361684/code-marked-as-deleted-does-not-look-good). Cruzándome los dedos para que sea bien recibida jejeje.

Comment: ya tiene 4 votos positivos... por lo cual esta perfecto... esperemos que siga avanzando...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

El problema es para toda la red.

Por lo cual, como no se puede dar una respuesta solo para este sitio, la misma se publico en [meta StackExchange](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/361684/code-marked-as-deleted-does-not-look-good).

Comment: Lamentablemente no todos los sitios que soportan código tiene modo oscuro todavía. Ref [Plans for dark mode for all Stack Exchange sites](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/359739/289691)

Comment: Claro.. pero como nos impacta aca tanto como a todos los sitios internacionales, hay que ponerlo mas general...

Comment: Sí, sí.... ninguna objeción al respecto, sólo acotando que por el momento el volumen de usuarios afectados son los afortunados de tener el modo oscuro... ya quisiera tener ese problema en Web Applications :D